# Was heat or thermal equipment used during search and rescue efforts for Uruguayan Air Force Flight 571?

Tags: accidents, search-and-rescue

[Uruguayan Air Force Flight 571](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruguayan_Air_Force_Flight_571) crashed in the Andes mountains on 13 October 1972. Was thermal or heat imaging equipment utilized for flight 571s search and rescue attempts? Such equipment dates back to as early as 1950.

Comment: What was the ambient temperature in the area of S&R efforts?  AFAIK, thermal imaging equipment is not very effective for certain types of S&R when the ambient temperature is above a certain threshold.  This was likely even more true 51 years ago.

Comment: How do you know such equipment wasn't used?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect, although there were some examples of thermal imaging cameras in the early 70s the technology wasn't very good, it wasn't until the 80s that it improved enough for this type of use case.

Comment: Also such technologies were often very expensive and only army could have them (and it requires trained personal). I assume it was not the priority of the South American armies/air forces to get such technology (and if they had, probably it was used on navy)

Comment: I think the suggestion that the Uruguayan military had thermal or IR cameras in 1972 is extremely dubious. Without support for that assertion, the question makes no sense.

Comment: I edited to remove the unsubstantiated presumption that it was NOT used.  Matt, if you know for certain that wasn't used please feel free to roll back my edit, but we'd like to ask that you provide enough information showing it wasn't to justify the original wording.